# What about something similar to StackOverflow for webmasters?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Being a very big fan of StackOverflow, I was just thinking that it would be really great if there was something like StackOverflow for webmasters.

I did some searching and it seems that there aren't many popular websites for webmasters. At least not as popular as StackOverflow is for programmers.

I imagine that, on the business side, it should be profitable enough to be considered. The topic is very popular and would not just be among webmasters. A lot of people are interested in this, basically anyone who has a website or a blog.

There are so many things that can be advertised on such a site (web hosting for example, among other things), that it could eventually be more profitable than StackOverflow and ServerFault. ;)

I think it can be really useful, there are so many topics related to webmasters, e.g. hosting, search engine crawling, online advertising, SEO, moderation... you name it!

Comment: Cleaned up, but the question still reads like a keyword stuffer.

Answer (score 12):

Just to fix SEO: [webmasters stack overflow](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

## https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I can sort of see what Waleed is getting at here.

While there are definitely webmaster topics that *can* fit (as noted by others in the answers), there are a bunch that don't, too.

What about questions on search engine optimization, advertising, hosting and so forth? These don't fit anywhere in the trilogy.

Comment: hmmm, it's time to consider a quadrilogy then :)

Comment: Hmmm.... If your thinking what I think you thinking.... Then don't. All the propoganda about the Trilogy I have done will just be shattered! Shattered I tell you. Complete the trilogy is. Listen to your inner Yoda! :)

Comment: @Jeff - What you may be skirting around is that there is no place for discussion about the "business of software/computers." Not "business" as in running a business; but industry talk. Search optimization, marketing, hosting, resources, best practices, career talk... they all fall between the cracks. Maybe that is a missing piece (think "Joel on Software"-style discussions). Do you know anyone who might be interested in such a place?

Answer (score 3):

What about "Webmastering" isn't programming (Stackoverflow), systems adminstration (Serverfault) or design (Doctype)?

Comment: what does this have to do with the suggestion? System adiminstration is not programming, superuser is also not for programmers, only stackoverflow is. I really don't get your answer.

Comment: Actually a new webiste has to be about something other than programming, because stackoverflow is already for that. Webmastering is a technical topic just like system administration, actually I find it even more popular.

Comment: @Waleed; cletus is pointing out that (most) webmastering topics are already covered by SO family sites http://stackoverflow.com/ and http://serverfault.com/ and the affiliated site http://doctype.com/. Thus there's no real need for a new site. This has everything to do with the suggestion.

Comment: @Jonik, I appreciate your comment but I don't think this is true. Actually I got a handful of webmaster-related questions closed on stackoverflow because they are not programming questions. I admit that they don't fit in there and it's not unfair that my questions were closed, unfortunately this kind of questions don't fit on any of the sites, this is the reason behind my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you scanned the list of [Where you can ask questions that aren't programming questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)?

WebHostingTalk comes to mind in terms of the hosting side of things.

And if you think the venture into a site on very similar topics already covered by SOFU would be more profitable/popular than the original flavour, you could always see how you sell your scoops of icecream when [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) is open.

You could even better WHT when focussed around the business of sites and SEO and advertising and such.

Comment: stackoverflow is not the only website for programmers, but it's the most popular. This is what I meant by a website for webmasters, it doesn't have to be the only one. Besides, webmastering is more than only hosting.