# Confirm policy on AdSense and advertising related questions?

Tags: support, close-reasons

This was recently asked on Super User: *https://superuser.com/questions/32936/how-much-traffic-is-needed-to-earn-1-in-google-adsense-closed*

This was another similar question: *https://superuser.com/questions/19260/how-many-hits-per-day-to-generate-revenue-via-adsense-closed*

This would include AdSense and related advertising questions. Am I correct that these type of questions are not allowed on any of the sites? I just want to make sure I am flagging and voting to close these questions for the right reasons.

Note: The questions above have now been deleted, but you can see the titles of the questions, which gives the scope of the question.

Comment: **`Note:`** those two questions have since been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confirmed policy as supported by the moderators and the Super User Team:

**Advertising questions regarding AdSense and profiting from a website is not allowed on Super User**

This is not computer software or hardware related, and a marketing exercise. These questions will be closed and deleted without warning and explanation.

Thank you. There is nothing more to see here. Move along now.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of any of our sites where this is appropriate.

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> If your question is about:
>
> - networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no
>     source code, ask on Server Fault.
> - general computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on Super
>     User.
> - web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on
>     Doctype.

I do not see how adsense would fall into any of these territories. They should really be asked on Google's discussion groups.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact dupe but it is related enough that there might be some useful information for you here:

[What about something similar to StackOverflow for webmasters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/what-about-something-similar-to-stackoverflow-for-webmasters)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it seems to me that fits on a site for people who manage websites, which does not currently exist in the LOJ.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing these questions would open the door to any number of business-related questions. Strictly speaking, these are not of any sort of technical nature.

Answer (score 0):

We definitely do not want to allow any questions on advertising networks, making money online, or blogging-related stuff on Super User.

I've been closing and quickly deleting them =)