# Where to ask about Google Adsense

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently, I asked a question on Super User about Google Adsense [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1448454/how-to-get-out-of-the-google-adsense-login-loop). I figured it wasn't really Stack Overflow material, and the ask question wizard on Stack Overflow directed me to Super User.

Anyways, I wanted to know: Where should we ask about *services* instead of the normal code and software questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functional *use* of and *configuration* of Adsense should be on topic on our [**Webmasters site**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=adsense) (also technically on topic on our [Webapps site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=adsense); although, a bit more of a tenuous fit).

For a bit more background on the Super User policy, I found this post: [Confirm policy on adsense and advertising related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19078/confirm-policy-on-adsense-and-advertising-related-questions).